# Convert decimal representing time to hour, minutes, seconds

Tags: math, date, time

I have a decimal. The range of this decimal is between 0 and 23.999999. This decimal represents a time. For example, if the decimal is 0.25, then the time it represents is 12:15 AM. If the decimal is 23.50, the time it represents is 11:30 PM.

I have three variables:
    - Hours
    - Minutes
    - Seconds

Using this decimal, how do I fill in the `Hours`, `Minutes`, and `Seconds` values?

Comment: Judging from the username, probably a .NET language :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, here's an answer in C#, but it's generally the same idea in most languages:

```
int hours = (int)hoursDecimal;
decimal minutesDecimal = ((hoursDecimal - hours) * 60);
int minutes = (int)minutesDecimal;
int seconds = (int)((minutesDecimal - minutes) * 60);
```

Comment: int seconds = (minutesAsADecimal - minutesAsAnInt) * 60?

Comment: Wont the conversion to int round up the hour part, giving an incorrect result if the remainder is > .5

Comment: @DavidB conversion to `int` always rounds down, not up.

Comment: I was using Cint in vb, which doesn't behave like this this so they must be different

Answer (score 4):

The hours should be pretty easy.

There are 60 minutes in 1 hour, so get the decimal part, multiply it by 60, and take the integer.  Take the decimal again, multiply it again by 60, and you have your seconds.

For example, let's take the number `20.38490`

We know it's hour 20, or 8 PM.

This leaves us with the number `.38490`

Multiplying with 60, we get 23.094 minutes.

Multiplying `.094` with 60, we get 5 seconds.

Comment: More helpful than above!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, by the way, It's also language agnostic. +1

Answer (score 1):

you can use the floor function to strip off the hours and leave the minuites and seconds as a fraction of an hour. Then you can use the floor function again to strip off the minuites as a fraction of an hour. you are then left with the seconds ( as fractions of an hour )

below a simple example to print hours and mins sunrise is in fractional hours since midnight

```
printf( "sunrise %ld:%ld, \n", 
             (long)floor( sunrise ),
                 (long)(floor( sunrise * 60 ) - 60 * floor( sunrise )) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever language you use, you can do this using the math functions: MOD and FLOOR/TRUNC

Let "dec" be the decimal variable

```
trunc(mod(dec, 1)) => hours
trunc(mod(dec * 60, 60)) => minutes
trunc(mod(dec * 3600, 60)) => seconds
```

In C#, you can truncate a decimal to int using just explicit casting, e.g.

```
int seconds = (int) ((dec * 3600) % 60)
```