# PHP - Calculate Pace min/km from seconds and meters

Tags: php, time, calculator

I'm trying to calculate my min/km average of my total run.

Currently I have ran ($this->totaltime) 3113 seconds, ($this->distance) 6313.59 and my pace should be 08:13 min/km (yes this was very slow!)

Code I'm using:

```
// Pace
function getPace() {
    $dis_pace = $this->distance / 1000;
    $pace = $this->totaltime / $dis_pace / 60;
    return $pace;
}
```

I think I'm missing something here..

[EDIT] The problem is I get 8.21 but need to have the results in time 08:13. [/EDIT]

Anybody?

Comment: And what is the problem now ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP syntax, but I think you just change the order of operations.  Will this work?
` $pace = $this->(totaltime / 60) / $dis_pace;`

Comment: @onskee That doesn't make a difference here, would be the same as: `1 + 2` == `2 + 1` or `1 * 2` == `2 * 1`

Comment: Rizier is correct, won't make a difference.

Comment: It certainly makes a difference. Parenthesis are important.  `(3113 / 60) / (6313.59 / 1000) = 8.2177`   `3113 / 60 / 6313.59 / 1000 = 8.217722933122571e-6`

Comment: Ok @onskee it does make a difference, BUT. In this case I get 8.2177229331226 .. but I know the pace should be (0)8.13. How would I get this number?

Comment: add this line before return `$pace=intval($pace).':'.ceil(($pace-intval($pace))*60);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697970/convert-decimal-representing-time-to-hour-minutes-seconds

Comment: Thanks Shaiful! Correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
// Pace
function getPace() {
    $dis_pace = $this->distance / 1000;

    //getting seconds per km
    $pace = $this->totaltime / $dis_pace;

    //getting minutes from $pace
    $min = floor($pace / 60);

    //adding 0 before,  if lower than 10
    $min = ($min > 10) ? $min : '0'.$min;

    //getting remaining seconds
    $sec = $pace % 60;

    //adding 0 before, if lower than 10
    $sec = ($sec > 10) ? $sec : '0'.$sec;

    return $min.":".$sec;
}
```

Comment: And Bari has the complete version. Thanks Bari!