# How to convert a decimal into time, eg. HH:MM:SS

Tags: php

I am trying to take a decimal and convert it so that I can echo it as hours, minutes, and seconds.

I have the hours and minutes, but am breaking my brain trying to find the seconds. Been googling for awhile with no luck. I'm sure it is quite simple, but nothing I have tried has worked. Any advice is appreciated!

Here is what I have:

```
function convertTime($dec)
{
    $hour = floor($dec);
    $min = round(60*($dec - $hour));
}
```

Like I said, I get the hour and minute without issue. Just struggling to get seconds for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: In what format is that "decimal"?

Comment: what you have doesn't seem right also. Can you provide a sample input and expected output ?

Comment: The decimal is nothing special. Something like 5.67891234.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert decimal number to time or vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345599/how-to-convert-decimal-number-to-time-or-vice-versa)

Comment: Also, the output is expected to just be a number for hour, a number for min, and a number for sec that I can then use to print a HTML page.

Comment: But what does that number represent? Hours?

Comment: the possible duplicate is tagged c# but there is an answer with the general formula for converting decimal time to regular

Comment: Sorry. Yes the number represents hours. And this is not a duplicate. The post you linked to converts to hours and minutes, which I already do. I was having issue with the getting seconds.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If `$dec` is in hours (`$dec` since the asker specifically mentioned a **dec**imal):

```
function convertTime($dec)
{
    // start by converting to seconds
    $seconds = ($dec * 3600);
    // we're given hours, so let's get those the easy way
    $hours = floor($dec);
    // since we've "calculated" hours, let's remove them from the seconds variable
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    // calculate minutes left
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    // remove those from seconds as well
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
    // return the time formatted HH:MM:SS
    return lz($hours).":".lz($minutes).":".lz($seconds);
}

// lz = leading zero
function lz($num)
{
    return (strlen($num) < 2) ? "0{$num}" : $num;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That makes more sense than what I was trying to do. :)

Comment: Instead of creating the `lz` function, you can use the native `str_pad` function, from PHP: `str_pad($num, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)`

Comment: @elboletaire Very true, I just happened to rip this out of some old, old class of mine.

Comment: Just a note: I don't agree with the community edit made adding the explicit `(int)` cast to that first line of the `convertTime()` function.  The edit note said something about casting `$dec` as an `(int)` for rounding - if you want to round off the seconds, just use `round()` in the appropriate place.

Comment: In fact, since the asker specifically asked about a *decimal*, I removed the `(int)` cast.  Doesn't make much sense to truncate the hours variable and yet still do minute and second calculations (since if you round the hours variable, there won't **be** any minutes or seconds!)

Answer (score 16):

Very simple solution in one line:

```
echo gmdate('H:i:s', floor(5.67891234 * 3600));
```

Comment: @Crontab Did not think about it :) Thanks.

Comment: Does it matter if you use `date()` instead of `gmdate()`?

Comment: @Staysee decimal time, as timestamp, as I think, defined in UTC timezone. Otherwise it will be shifted to the server's timezone and you may never get, for example, 0 and so on.

Comment: how can i convert   17:30 -> 17.5

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi  like this, for example `$time = strtotime('17:30') - strtotime('midnight'); echo $time / 3600;`

Comment: Caution: If you had a number of hours greater than one day in decimal (e.g. a stopwatch) and wanted hours:minutes this would loop round as it will never read more than 24.

Answer (score 5):

Everything upvoted didnt work in my case.
I have used that solution to convert decimal hours and minutes to normal time format.
i.e.

```
function clockalize($in){

    $h = intval($in);
    $m = round((((($in - $h) / 100.0) * 60.0) * 100), 0);
    if ($m == 60)
    {
        $h++;
        $m = 0;
    }
    $retval = sprintf("%02d:%02d", $h, $m);
    return $retval;
}


clockalize("17.5"); // 17:30
```

Comment: what about inverse  17:30 -> 17.5

Answer (score 1):

This is a great way and avoids problems with floating point precision:

```
function convertTime($h) {
    return [floor($h), (floor($h * 60) % 60), floor($h * 3600) % 60];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but

```
$variabletocutcomputation = 60 * ($dec - $hour);
$min = round($variabletocutcomputation);
$sec = round((60*($variabletocutcomputation - $min)));
```