# Converting seconds to time with two decimal places

Tags: php, datetime, mathematical-expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert seconds into days, hours, minutes, seconds in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-seconds-in-php)
>   [How to convert a decimal into time, eg. HH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102680/how-to-convert-a-decimal-into-time-eg-hhmmss)

what I am doing here is I am saving posts time as UTC in mysql, after retrieving the time stamp from sql I am using `strtotime()` to convert it into seconds, and then am adding offset time to these seconds to show current local time. Now the question here is when I try to reconvert these seconds into hours, say for example

```
$seconds = 330*60 //Thats 5.30 hours and 60 seconds gives me 19800 as an output
```

now when I reconvert it back to hours its showing me 5.50 instead of 5.30

```
sprintf ("%.2f", 19800/60/60); //Output of 5.50 instead I want is 5.30
```

I know it's a mathematical expression am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated with a clean explanation.

Comment: But [330 minutes to hours](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=330+minutes+to+hours) ?? 5 hours 30 minutes != 5.30 hours

Comment: if you set the proper timezone in your script, you shouldnt need to do that conversion at all

Comment: I want the output as 5.30 and not 5.50

Comment: @Gordon I just want to show that 19800 is +5.30 offset at front .. I know I don't need it in my code functioning as I just add these to `strtotime()` and use `date()` to show local time

Comment: @RandomGuy I'm trying to understand your question. Mathematically `19800/60/60 = 5.50` Where do you get 5.30?

Comment: 5 and a half hours, 5 hours and 30 minutes

Comment: @sachleen Ya I know mathematically it is 5.50 but what if I want to convert it to 5.30?and for you guys out here I am using simple `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");` and I guess this has nothing to do with my question...

Comment: Oh I get it. Then you can just `time = 5.5; hours = (int)time; minutes=(time-hours)*60`

Comment: @sachleen that's right expression..

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8273826/24950) from the thread I linked to will help.

Comment: I still dont get why you calculate that instead of using date('P') on your regular timestamp in that timezone.

Comment: @Gordon I am using this nowhere in my code functioning, I am just using this to ouput a user at what offset he is at..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but this works:

```
$original = (19800 / 60 / 60);
$hours = floor($original);
$minutes = ($original - $hours) * 60;
```

Or this is probably better using modulus:

```
$hours = floor(19800 / 60 / 60);
$minutes = (19800 / 60) % 60;
```

Comment: haha nice this is good, any better solution than this? or you'll be getting a green tick..