# Convert float to HH:MM format

Tags: php

I have a question about formatting a string or float.

So essentially I have these numbers which need to be outputted as shown:

```
9.8333333333333 -> 09:50
5.5555555555556 -> 05:33
10.545454545455 -> 10:33
1.3333333333333 -> 01:20
20.923076923077 -> 20:55
```

Here is the function I wrote that is doing a terrible job at what I need it to.

```
function getTime($dist, $road) {
    $roads = array('I' => 65, 'H' => 60, 'M' => 55, 'S' => 45);
    $time = $dist / $roads[$road];
    return round($time -1) . ':' . substr((float)explode('.', $time)[1] * 60, 0, 2);
}
```

So if anyone has any ideas id appreciate it, i've tried the DateTime class but wasn't able to format the numbers properly for it to be used.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look to this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1345609/1972100

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) for the 0 padding, [`fmod`](http://php.net/fmod) to extract the fraction, and optionally [`round`](http://php.net/round) if flooring the seconds is unacceptable:

```
$time = 15.33;
echo sprintf('%02d:%02d', (int) $time, fmod($time, 1) * 60);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm and seriously saved me! Thanks Corbin! I used the round. So here's the math I used: `sprintf('%02d:%02d', (int) $time, round(fmod($time, 1) * 60))`

Comment: what if the float value is like 7.96?

Answer (score 1):

Trim off the integer portion of the float:

```
$time = 9.83333333333;
$hourFraction = $time - (int)$time;
```

Multiply by the number of units (minutes) in the greater unit (hour):

```
$minutes = $hourFraction * 60;
```

Echo:

```
$hours = (int)$time;
echo str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: This also worked, just not as efficient as the method posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$example = 1.3333;
```

Get the fractional element of your time by doing modulo 1

```
$remainder = $example % 1;
$minutes = 60 * $remainder;
```

You can then use `(int)$example` or `floor($example)` to get the hour component of your time.

```
$hour = floor($example);
echo $hour." ".$minutes;
```

Comment: For some reason mod 1 wasn't giving me the remainder, not quite sure why.  But the above did give me my answer, thanks anyways!  Had the same thinking as you.